# Power Bi create comma seperated list string where ids match

Tags: powerbi

Im really new to Power Bi, I created the following table:

```
ID | POST_ID |
0  | 11      |
0  | 12      |
0  | 13      |
0  | 18      |
0  | 21      |
1  | 14      |
1  | 15      |
2  | 16      |
2  | 17      |
2  | 19      |
2  | 20      |
```

Now I need to pass this ids to an api as a comma seperated list, so I want to transform the table to:

```
ID | POST_ID        |
0  | 11,12,13,18,21 |
1  | 14,15          |
2  | 16,17,19,20    |
```

But can't manage to do this. I assume it must be fairly easy to do? I have no clue to start, I've been messing around in the query editor now for a few hours and googling wont bring me much help either so far!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

## Here is a solution

```
let
    t=#table({"ID", "POST_ID"},{{0, 11},{0, 12},{0, 13},{0, 18},{0, 21},{1, 14},{1, 15},{2, 16},{2, 17},{2, 19},{2, 20}}),
    group = Table.Group(t, {"ID"}, {{"val_list", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([POST_ID], Number.ToText), ",")}})
in
    group
```

[image]

---

### But... are you sure you finally need a text string?

If you pass result to API, perhaps you'd better pass a list of numbers

[image]

So your code should look like this

```
let
    t=#table({"ID", "POST_ID"},{{0, 11},{0, 12},{0, 13},{0, 18},{0, 21},{1, 14},{1, 15},{2, 16},{2, 17},{2, 19},{2, 20}}),
    group = Table.Group(t, {"ID"}, {{"val_list", each [POST_ID]}})
in
    group
```